# Progress bar does not show progress during processing

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I am trying to show the progress in the progress bar, but it is not running, I have seen several solutions but none has solved me.

This is part of the code that I am using :

```py
def progress_changed(self, progress):
    self.progressalg.setValue(progress)


def AdicionarDatosparcelas(self):
    self.usuario_origen = self.cfgdlg.v_usuario_o.text()
    self.contrasena_origen = self.cfgdlg.v_contrasena_o.text()
    self.usuario_destino = self.cfgdlg.v_usuario_d.text()
    self.contrasena_destino = self.cfgdlg.v_contrasena_d.text()

    progressMessageBar = self.iface.messageBar().createMessage("Insertando parcelas en la base de datos...")
    self.progressalg = QProgressBar()
    self.progressalg.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
    progressMessageBar.layout().addWidget(self.progressalg)
    self.iface.messageBar().pushWidget(progressMessageBar, Qgis.Info)

    f = QgsProcessingFeedback()
    f.progressChanged.connect(self.progress_changed)        

    geom_column = None
    uri_origen = QgsDataSourceUri()
    uri_origen.setConnection(self.servidor_origen, str(self.puerto_origen), self.basedato_origen, self.usuario_origen,
                             self.contrasena_origen,
                             QgsDataSourceUri.SslDisable)
    uri_origen.setParam('key', 'mi_prinx')
    uri_origen.setParam('checkPrimaryKeyUnicity','0')


    uri_origen.setDataSource("catastro", "parcelas", geom_column)
    parcela_origen = QgsVectorLayer(uri_origen.uri(), 'parcela_origen', "postgres")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(parcela_origen, True)

    uri_destino = QgsDataSourceUri()
    uri_destino.setConnection(self.servidor_destino, str(self.puerto_destino), self.basedato_destino,
                              self.usuario_destino, self.contrasena_destino,
                              QgsDataSourceUri.SslDisable)

    uri_destino.setParam('key', 'mi_prinx')
    uri_origen.setParam('checkPrimaryKeyUnicity', '0')
    uri_destino.setDataSource("catastro", "parcelas", geom_column)
    parcela_destino = QgsVectorLayer(uri_destino.uri(), 'parcela_destino', "postgres")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(parcela_destino, True)

    processing.run("etl_load:appendfeaturestolayer", {
        'SOURCE_LAYER': parcela_origen,
        'SOURCE_FIELD': 'mi_prinx',
        'TARGET_LAYER': parcela_destino,
        'TARGET_FIELD': 'mi_prinx',
        'ACTION_ON_DUPLICATE': 1}, feedback=f)
    self.iface.messageBar().pushSuccess('parcelas exportadas', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I can help directly but you can run the following as it perfectly shows the progress bar and the `progressChanged` calls correctly the `progress_changed` function (tested before answering)

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingContext, QgsProcessingFeedback, QgsProject

bar = QProgressBar()
bar.setRange(0,100)
iface.mainWindow().statusBar().addWidget(bar)
# Could be replaced by the following if you want same position as the default QGIS component for progress bar
# face.mainWindow().statusBar().insertPermanentWidget(0, bar)

alg_params = { 'FIELD' : 'fid', 'INPUT' : '/usr/share/qgis/resources/data/world_map.gpkg|layername=countries', 'OPERATOR' : 4, 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'VALUE' : '1000' }

def progress_changed(progress):
    bar.setValue(progress)

feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
feedback.progressChanged.connect(progress_changed)

context = QgsProcessingContext()
extracted = processing.run('native:extractbyattribute', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=False)

# Comment if you want to be sure to see the progress bar position before removing it
iface.mainWindow().statusBar().removeWidget(bar)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas, this code helped me to rectify the one I was using